# How to store values returned by recursive function in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have a nested array -

```
$array1 = array(
        array(
            '#type' => 'rev',
            '#rev' => 0,
            '#rev_info' => array(
                'status' => 'available',
                'default' => FALSE,
                'open_rev' => FALSE,
                'conflict' => FALSE,
            ),
            'children' => array(
                array(
                    '#type' => 'rev',
                    '#rev' => 1,
                    '#rev_info' => array(
                        'status' => 'available',
                        'default' => FALSE,
                        'open_rev' => FALSE,
                        'conflict' => FALSE,
                    ),
                    'children' => array(
                        array(
                            '#type' => 'rev',
                            '#rev' => 2,
                            '#rev_info' => array(
                                'status' => 'available',
                                'default' => FALSE,
                                'open_rev' => TRUE,
                                'conflict' => TRUE,
                            ),
                            'children' => array(),
                        ),
                        array(
                            '#type' => 'rev',
                            '#rev' => 3,
                            '#rev_info' => array(
                                'status' => 'available',
                                'default' => FALSE,
                                'open_rev' => FALSE,
                                'conflict' => FALSE,
                            ),
                            'children' => array(
                                array(
                                    '#type' => 'rev',
                                    '#rev' => 4,
                                    '#rev_info' => array(
                                        'status' => 'available',
                                        'default' => TRUE,
                                        'open_rev' => TRUE,
                                        'conflict' => FALSE,
                                    ),
                                    'children' => array(),
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    '#type' => 'rev',
                    '#rev' => 5,
                    '#rev_info' => array(
                        'status' => 'available',
                        'default' => FALSE,
                        'open_rev' => TRUE,
                        'conflict' => TRUE,
                    ),
                    'children' => array(),
                )
            )
        )
    );

    $x = $this->creator($array1);
    print_r($x);
```

I need to store all the **#rev** values in an array. I have written the code which loops over this array recursively but in the end it's returning only **0**. 
The code I have written is:

```
public function creator($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        $x = $value['#rev'];
        $storage[$x] = $x;
        if (count($value['children'])) {
            $this->creator($value['children']);
        }
    }
}
```

I want the `creator` function to return an array with values 0 to 5 but it returns 0 only.

Where I am making the mistake. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning any value from the function. You need to return some value from the function to store that value in a variable :

```
public function creator($arr) {

      $storage  = array();    

    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        $x = $value['#rev'];
        $storage[$x] = $x;
        if (count($value['children'])) {
            return creator($value['children']);
        }
    }
   return $storage;
}
```

Or you can do whatever you are doing but just call the value by reference :

```
    creator(&$array1);
print_r($array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function creator ($arr){
    if(!is_array($arr)) return []; //safeguard in case a non-array is supplied
    $results = []; //will be filled with the #rev values
    foreach($arr as $value){
        //if #rev is found, add its value to results
        if(isset($value['#rev'])) $results[]=$value['#rev'];

        //if children are found, process them recursively and merge the
        // sub-results into the main results array
        if(isset($value['children'])) 
            array_merge($results, creator($value['children']));

    }
    return $results;
};
```